# Eclipse Kepler - How To Maintain Multiple Window Order Across Restarts

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I open multiple windows when using Eclipse on a machine running Windows 7.

I would like to be able to boot Eclipse and find the windows displayed (stacked) in the Taskbar in the same order as I left them when I last exited Eclipse.

With Eclipse Indigo, the order in which the windows where opened and displayed in the Windows Taskbar could be predicted by the order in which the windows had previously been selected and viewed.

By activating (selecting to view) the windows one-at-a-time from left to right just before exiting, I was guaranteed to find them opened in same order next time I booted Eclipse.

Eclipse Kepler seems to set the window ordering in some other way that I cannot predict.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should open a defect against Platform -> UI for this...

We could likely re-arrange the MApplication's children's order to move any window that goes active to the end of the list. That would mean on startup it'd appear on top (they're rendered first to last in the children list...